# Control parts of code through external on off config file?

Tags: php

I want to have a config file that basically says something like (Account: on/off), where an admin can choose on or off. And then, in my main script, i want a bunch of if else statements that says if its on, do this, if off, do this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

config.php:

```
<?php
$account = 'off';
```

main_script.php:

```
<?php
include('config.php');

if ($account == 'on') {
    //do this
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

Comment: One question though, inside the if statements are going to be blocks of html code, can i just use an echo and wrap the long block of code in quotes?

Comment: I recommend reading [PHP Manual :: Basic Syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php).

Answer (score 0):

Config files usually define global constants available everywhere in your code and often seen in the variable `$GLOBALS['config']`. Config files are normal PHP files that get included using include() or better include_once() at the very top of your applications main file.

```
include_once('config.php');
if ($GLOBALS['config']['admin']) doThis();
else doThat();
```

http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.globals.php

Comment: How do you figure this is "most often"? I've never seen someone create their own fake superglobal. `$_GLOBALS` isn't something provided by PHP. It's not a constant either. Constants are created with `define()`. You and your strange answers today...

Comment: "most often" is subjective. $_GLOBALS is $GLOBALS. Constants not in a syntactical but in a semantical sense. However ... the answer is here anyway: Use a config file and put there your config vars.

Comment: Google about `$GLOBALS['config']`: http://www.google.com/search?q=%22%24GLOBALS[config]%22

Comment: Note: `$_GLOBALS` does not exist. I already did fix my post. However, I do not recommend using `$GLOBALS` since this variable might be used by included 3rd party code as well and is therefore not safe. To encapsulate an application configuration it's far better to use a singleton class or a static class or even PHP constants that may be created with `define`.